# Download pics not shown in "DCIM" folder to PC

Tags: iphone

When my Iphone is connected to the PC Itunes shows it contains 301 photos in the storage bar at the bottom of the Window. However when I check the DCIM folder in Windows Explorer, there are only 94 photos.

These are photos taken with the Iphone.

Comment: That count probably includes images and icons used by apps. It might also be including images cached by your web browser.

Answer (score 1):

The bar in iTunes counts **photos in Photo Stream** which are not contained within DCIM. These photos, whilst they might have been taken on the device, can't be obtained over USB.